# How to make a bomb function in Perlenspiel/Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Javascript/Perlenspiel

Hello, I'm trying to make a function/code that will let the player pick up the item "BOMB" and then activate it anywhere on the map by pressing "b". The bomb will destroy any walls within a 2 bead radius of the player.

How do I get started doing this? I'm not familiar with objects or key presses like this.

This is the only thing I have so far:

```
//Player
var PLAYER = {
    x : 1, // The x and y of where the player is now
    y : 1,
    StartX : 1,
    StartY : 1,
    glyph : "➽",
    color : 0x0000FF,
    data : "player",
    //dead : false,
}


var BOMB = {
    x : 3,
    y : 3,
    glyph : "♾",
    color : 0x000000,
    data : "bomb",
}
\var dataAtPlayer = PS.data(PLAYER.x, PLAYER.y);

    if(dataAtPlayer ="bomb"){
        PS.debugClear();
        PS.debug("You picked up a bomb! Press the b key to use it!\n");
        if(key == 98){
            eraseBead(PLAYER.x + 1, 0);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: @JeremyRoberts As you are a beginner, you should read some books on JavaScript. Whatever you are trying to achieve is almost impossible for a beginner. I read a book named "Beginning JavaScript" to get started with JavaScript. You can also see some tutorials on JavaScript if you don't like reading books.

Comment: @Arjun Well, after fiddling with my coding a little more in the PS.keyDown section I have updated it and got a little farther.

Comment: to key process you have to use key code and event listener

Comment: building a bomb for school - been done :p

Comment: @ShohanurRahaman Yes, I was able to get that far. I got it to acknowledge the player picking up the item. But once I press b, I get the error PS.data y argument not a number.
Edit: I was able to solve my above problem, but it doesn't seem to delete the block infront of the player.

Comment: "I'm not familiar with objects or key presses like this." sounds like you need to do some research  (googling). This isn't actually a free coding service.

Answer (score 2):

To get started you'll need more objects, these include:

- Wall
- Map

You're game loop will include (pseudocode):

```
while(!player.isDead)
{
    ...
    if(keyPress==KeyToPickupBOMB)
    {
         if(PlayerIsOnBomb(Player,Map))
         {
             PlayerPicksUpBomb(Player,Map)
         }
    }
    ...
    if(keyPress=="B")
    {
        if(PlayerHasBomb(Player))
        {
            explodeBomb(Player,Map)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The function to explode a wall would be

```
function explodeBomb(Player,Map)
{
    //Check for Borders
    for(int x = Player.X-2; x<=Player.X+2;x++)
    {
         for(int y = Player.y-2; y<=Player.y+2;y++)
         {
              if(Map[x][y] is a Wall)
              { 
                   Map[x][y] is now empty space
              }
          }
     }
}
```